# how to set size of the button image dynamically in c#?

Tags: image, winforms, c#-4.0, button

I'm trying to set the size of the image of the button dynamically like this

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dlCatObj.ReadCat().Rows)
        {
            Button btnObj = new Button();
            int btnID = Convert.ToInt32(row["CAT_ID"]);
            string btnName = row["CAT_NAME"].ToString();
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(row["CAT_IMAGE"]))
            {
                photo = (byte[])(row["CAT_IMAGE"]);
                btnObj.Image  = (ByteToImage(photo));
                btnObj.Image.Size = new size(100, 80); //Here I have a Problem
            }
            btnObj.Name = btnID.ToString();
            btnObj.Text = btnName;
           btnObj.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
            this.plCategory.Controls.Add(btnObj);

        }
```

but I don't get the way how do I do this. Kindly guide me the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the image in the `Image` object then you can resize it by using `Bitmap` constructor.

For example if your image is stored in imgPhoto object:

```
Image imgPhoto = yourImage;
```

then you can create a new bitmap from the original source:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgPhoto, new Size(100,80));
```

Now your new image is resized to 100x80.